# I Need help coming up with back end server application design

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, architecture, serversocket

So I am programming a server in node.js for a project that a group and I are working on in class and we have to come up with an architectural design for our application. We are getting a little hung up on trying to design our back-end because the server we have has multiple services, like text chat, video streaming, and audio streaming and what not. Should we split up our back-end to have 3 different programs running to handle each one of the services or how should we go about doing this?

Comment: splitting will always help you maintain and scale your application, so why not to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

As node is a Single-Threaded, I would suggest building separate functions to operate efficiently at scale. Communicate between the programs via API's